# Custom Model Binding cannot access all fields MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, zurb-foundation, model-binding

Im trying to bind custom model, which looks approximately like this:

```
[ReadOnly(true)]
[DisplayName("User ID")]
public String ID { get; set; }
[DisplayName("User Name")]
[Required]
public String Name { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Change Password")]
[Required]
public bool ChangePassword { get; set; }
[DisplayName("New password")]
[Required]
public String NewPassword { get; set; }
public Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,bool>> Navigation { get; set; }
```

In order to make input form look better I separate different Navigation items with div panel:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class=".small-12.large-3.large-centered.columns">
        <h2>EditUser</h2>

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.Partial("ValidationSummary", @ViewData.ModelState)

            <div>
                <legend>User details</legend>

                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewPassword)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewPassword)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewPassword)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <div class="switch">
                        <input id="switch-off" type="radio" name="switch-x" checked />
                        <label for="switch-off">Keep</label>
                        <input id="switch-on" type="radio" name="switch-x" />
                        <label for="switch-on" id="offClick">Change</label>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @{
            int m = 0;
                }
                @{int k = 0;}
                @foreach (var item in Model.Navigation)
                {
                    <div class="panel">
                        @{String name = names.Keys.ToArray()[m];}
                        <h3>@name</h3>
                        <div class="editor-field">

                            @for (int i = 0; i < item.Value.Count; i += 3)
                            {

                                @:<div id="btnset_@k">
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    if (i + j < item.Value.Count)
    {

        String id = item.Key + "_" + item.Value.Keys.ToArray()[i + j];
        String value = item.Value.Values.ToArray()[i + j] ? "checked=\"checked\"" : String.Empty;

                                <input type="checkbox" id="@id" @value />
                                <label for="@id">@names[name][i + j]</label>

    }

}
                            @:</div>
                                                                                                                                            k++;
                            }

                        </div>
                    </div>
                            m++;

                }
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button" />
                </p>
            </div>
        }
```

The problem is when I derive Default DefaultModelBinder, the controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form contains no keys for radio button groups, which I have in the form. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not setting the name attribute that is necessary for binding.

Comment: @Daniele, post that as an answer so you can get credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the name attribute that is necessary for binding.